# Precise definition of distinct vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

What is the precise definition of 'distinct vectors'?
In particular, are the vectors (2, 1) and (4, 2) distinct, seeing as they are multiples of each other?

Comment: I believe the definition is that distinct vectors are those that differ in any way whatsoever, including norm.

Comment: I don't know for certain, but what I'd say is that vectors $u$ and $v$ are distinct if and only if $u - v /neq 0$. This is the standard sort of thing, I believe. :)

Comment: The vectors you give are called _parallel_.

Comment: Generally, distinct means not equal.  So, yes $(2,1) \ne (4,2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Distinct" means "different." The question of when two things are different is a difficult philosophical problem in general. However, when we speak of two distinct elements $x,y$ of a set, this means simply that $x\neq y$, meaning that $x$ and $y$ are not the same element. Two vectors are distinct unless they are the same element of the vector space. Since two vectors, at least one of which is nonzero, that are multiples of each other by a factor other than $1$ are not the same, they qualify as distinct.